# Rewrite_mod Redirect http://localhost/ to http://localhost/home/

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I can't seem to find any information on how to achive a rewrite to redirect `http://localhost:8888/` to `http://loclahost:8888/home/`

I tried:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://localhost:8888/website/home/
```

But that gives me an infinite loop.

I have the following rules already applied:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} home/ 
RewriteRule home/ http://localhost:8888/website/index.php [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ([a-z]*)/ 
RewriteRule ([a-z]*)/ http://localhost:8888/website/$1.php
```

I got this info from: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#moveddocroot

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: Yeh, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using:

```
RedirectMatch ^/website/$ http://localhost:8888/website/home/
```